# Member turns to undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've developed a jQuery plugin which has default options:

```
$.fn.incromentor.defaults = {
   max : 65355,
   min : 0
};
```

In the initialization of the plugin, I merge the user options with plugin default options using `$.extend`

```
function init( $elm, options )
{
    this.$element = $elm;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.incromentor.defaults, options ); 
}
```

So the problem is, if user sets `min`or `max` to `0`, that property turns to undefined!
Why is this and how can I store a simple 0?

Here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KDXa6/2/

**Edit**
After linting the code in JSLint, the error dissapeared so I suspect there was an obscure error in my typing.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/XYxTp/

Comment: it works even with jQuery 1.2.6. Haven't you just mistyped something, effectively executing something like `$.extend({}, undefined, options);`?

Comment: mmm, that's what I suspect... I've created a JSFiddle with the full code where I put a console.log() to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/KDXa6/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but you might want to take a look at the errors reported by the JS Lint button (in the JS Fiddle). They may amount to nothing, though.

Comment: JS Lint indications fixed something that fixed options settings in the constructor function. There were other logic errors that had to be fixed too, but the main error is gone!

Answer (score 0):

$.fn.incromentor.defaults = {} will overwrite your default options, so something else such as more_text, less_text is turned to undefined. Your Users should pass their options into the constructor such as

```
$('#myel').Incrementor({ max : 65355, min : 0});
```

--

$this to $(this) http://jsfiddle.net/KDXa6/1/

Comment: see updated anwswer, jsfiddle seems to be down so cant test right now

Comment: where $.fn.incromentor.defaults is being setted to {} ?